# How can I fix the SSL error of RStudio after the installation on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: rstudio

Right after the installation of RStudio (rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb) from the official site it doesn't start. This error pops up:

```
rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to run `sudo apt install libssl-dev` but that didn't help either since version 1.0.2 is required.

How can I get RStudio to run as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy workaround: Download `rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb` for **Ubuntu 16**. This works out of the box on my system and RStudio starts as expected.